# Motion detection using sound

Tags: android, audio, detection

I was thinking of implementing a motion detection by SOUND, to my app. However I'm still deciding on a good solution for this. One idea would be recording small chunks of sound and somehow comparing them. The other would be non-stop audio rec and somehow "feel" to sound spikes and trigger motion. 
I'm talking about detecting motion in the room, ambient motion.
The latter sounds better but is it implementable?

Comment: Are you talking about with a peripheral? (i.e. http://www.parallax.com/tabid/768/ProductID/92/Default.aspx) Or with only an android device?

Comment: Why do you want to use sound for motion detection?  Wouldn't an accelerometer be a better choice?

Comment: Relevant: http://www.extremetech.com/computing/128735-microsoft-creates-kinect-like-system-using-your-laptops-built-in-speaker-microphone

Comment: I want to use the mic to detect motion around the phone, not the motion of the phone itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could emit some sound and try to detect any differences or changes over time in the Doppler shift, spectrum and amplitude in any reflections returned to the microphone.  A textbook on RADAR technology might explain some of the DSP signal analysis needed.